# Class and File name exchangable?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I don't understand how the same variable can refer to a file name and to the class (with the same name as the file) that is in that file. Is there some magic bond with files and classes with the same name?

```
<?php

class Controller {

    public function model($model){

        require_once '../app/models/'.$model.'.php';

        return new $model;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is more about a convention than some magic in PHP.  It helps find classes if the file name is the same, this is both for people as well as an autoloader which can use the class name as the file name.

Comment: That, and if you had an autoloader set up, and were using unique namespaces, you wouldn't need the `require` line either. Yashar you may find [PSR-4: Autoloader](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) an informative read.